# Bootstrap - Portfolio image left, title and description right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create my portfolio website and I'm kind of stuck...

I want to make portfolio image to be on the left side, and title and description on the right side of it.

So, the structure would be:

Image - Text

Image - Text

Image - Text

I tried to write some code and I it works, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

```
<section class="section works" id="works">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="works-item col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="works-image col-md-6">
                            <img src="1.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-info col-md-6">
                            <h4 class="item-name">Some Title here</h4>
                            <p class="item-type">Description should be here</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

It's bootstrap 3

Comment: check out the Bootstrap “media object” - could be what you are loooking for

Comment: @gavgrif Sorry, I forgot to say. As I understood media object isn't "responsive" on mobile. On mobile I need it to be a classic structure, the image above the text.

Comment: you should be able to apply media queries of your onw to alter the layout in xs sized viewports - just changing from display: table-cell to display: table-row will do it -  .media-body, .media-left, .media-right {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: top;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have used is correct. but it will work in some devices as you have used col-md

if you want 
Image - Text

Image - Text

Image - Text

for all devices.

```html
<section class="section works" id="works">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="works-item col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="works-image col-xs-6">
                            <img src="1.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-info col-xs-6">
                            <h4 class="item-name">Some Title here</h4>
                            <p class="item-type">Description should be here</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section
```

if you want 40% for image and 60% for text use col-xs-4 col-xs-8 repectively

Comment: Thanks man, I just wanted to check if that's a good way to do it. I want a classic structure on mobile devices, full-width image and the text below, so it works fine. Thanks again